# A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create two sequential models in Keras for CNN deep learning and merge(concatenate) these two models before adding it into the dense layer. But I am getting the error:
    A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

```
    model_1 = models.Sequential()
    model_1.add(layers.Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu',
        input_shape=(TEXT_MAX_LENGTH, LENGTH_ALPHABET)))
    model_1.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
    model_1.add(layers.Flatten())

    model_2 = models.Sequential()
    model_2.add(layers.Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu',
        input_shape=(TEXT_MAX_LENGTH, LENGTH_ALPHABET)))
    model_2.add(layers.Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu'))
    model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(3))
    model_2.add(layers.Flatten())

    concat = Concatenate([model_1, model_2]) 

    merged_model = models.Sequential()      

    model.add(concat)


    model.add(layers.Dense(width_hidden, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=dropout))
    model.add(layers.Dense(width_output, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
           optimizer='adam',
           metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
       batch_size=batch_size,
       epochs=epochs,
       verbose=1,
       callbacks=callbacks_list,
       validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
       )
```

Comment: This is not going to work this way, you are mixing Sequential and Functional APIs, you have to implement this only with the Functional API.

Comment: Yes thats what the mistake was. Thanks.

Comment: why wouldn't u actually add over sequential rather than  adding second functional API?